# Is there a faster way (or more efficient) to stream triples/quads than RDFDataMgr.parse(..) or RDFParser..?

Tags: java, jena

I am looking to find more efficient ways to stream RDF quads/triples from large datasets. I have been using both `RDFDataMgr.parse(rdfStream, datasetLocation);` and `RDFParser.source(datasetLocation).parse(rdfStream);` however both solutions suffer when a dataset grows. I did an experiment to see how much time the RDFDataMgr takes to parse datasets of different sizes. I considered: 300000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 7500000, 10000000 as basis and then 182011590 (a real dataset). The processing is linear but it does take a lot of time. The average time for each dataset size is as follows:

```
300000 - 4421.1ms
500000 - 7184.6ms
1000000 - 14431.6ms
5000000 - 71926.3ms
7500000 - 116375.7ms
10000000 - 148588.8ms
```

On average, the parser is parsing 68265.38333 triples per second. This number was based on the average of benchmarking runs over all test datasets. It is actually quite time consuming considering that 300k triples take ~ 4s to be parsed

The PipedRDFIterator and PipedRDFStream were initialised as follows:

```
int buffer = (int) (size * 0.10);
PipedRDFIterator iterator =  new PipedRDFIterator(buffer, true, 50 , 10000);
PipedRDFStream rdfStream = new PipedTriplesStream((PipedRDFIterator) iterator);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

As expected, the larger dataset (182011590 triples) took much more time, 1450001ms (around 24 minutes). Interesting enough, on average the parser was parsing 125525 triples per second.

I do understand there there parsing is not just reading from a file and dumping it, but it includes syntax checking etc..., however, is there any way or any Jena parser which could speed up the parsing time?

I hope this makes sense to you.

Thanks!

Edit: I ran these benchmarks using the following VM parameters: -Xmx10g -Xms8g on a 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5, 16GB ram 2133 MHz, and an SSD drive

Comment: It depends on where the triples go - maybe that is slower than the parser. It also depends on the syntax fo the RDF - N-Triples/N-Quads are the fastest format, then Turtle/TriG then RDF/XML.

Comment: I used NTriples for these tests. So the triples as I understand should in the PipedRDFIterator.. I was basically doing the following:

`
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   iterator.next();
   totalQuadsProcessed++;
}
`

Comment: On machine (5y desktop, 32G Core i7) , the parser runs at 217K triples/s. Test data was BSBM 100e6 from "riot --sink --time bsbm-100m.nt.gz" (.gz is slightly slower 5%? than raw) from disk.  Disk vs SSD makes little difference when the large file written all at one time. If the data has large numbers of huge literals, things would have been different. (A 10G heap on a 16G machine risks swapping happening.)

Comment: @AndyS - any idea where JSON-LD ranks, with respect to your first comment?